# How to check through DataTables in a VB.NET loop

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, for-loop, grouping

I would like to insert data into Excel through VB.NET. The data is retrieved from a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Here's my snippet of code for the loop.

```
For h As Integer = 0 To ds2.Tables.Count - 1

    Dim dt As DataTable = ds2.Tables(h)

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim DT_CollectionDate_temp As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows(i)("CollectionDate").ToString())
            Dim str_CollectionDate = DT_CollectionDate_temp.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

            ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 1).Value = dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()

        If (prevBatchID <> dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()) AndAlso (prevBatchID <> dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()) Then
            batchIDTotal += dt.Rows(i)("BatchTotal")
            ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 2).Value = batchIDTotal

        End If

        ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 3).Value = str_CollectionDate.ToString()

            If (prevDate <> str_CollectionDate) AndAlso (prevBatchID <> dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()) Then
                If (dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString() = dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()) Then
                    If (prevDate <> str_CollectionDate) AndAlso (prevBatchID <> dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()) Then
                        batchTotalCount += dt.Rows(i)("RowTotalCount")
                        ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 4).Value = batchTotalCount
                    End If
                End If
            End If


            If (prevDate <> str_CollectionDate) AndAlso (prevBatchID <> dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()) Then
                If (dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString() = dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()) Then
                    If (prevDate <> str_CollectionDate) AndAlso (prevBatchID <> dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()) Then
                        TotalTransaction += dt.Rows(i)("RowTotalTransaction")
                        ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 5).Value = TotalTransaction
                        'ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 5).Value = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows(i)("RowTotalTransaction").ToString()))
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left
            ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 2).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right
            ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 3).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right
            ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 4).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right
            ws_Term.Cells(int_details_row, 5).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right

            prevDate = str_CollectionDate
            prevBatchID = dt.Rows(i)("KioskBatchID").ToString()

            int_details_row += 1

        Next
Next
```

The current output is like this
[image: The current data pass two DataTables (Merchant 0008 and Merchant 0007), thus the loop goes through the first one (resulting in the first two rows) and then the second one (resulting in the next three rows).]

The data that I ran (04-02-2021 until 07-02-2021) have two tables (because of two Merchants: 0007 and 0008 existing between the dates), thus the loop goes through the first one (resulting in the first two rows) and then the second one (resulting in the next three rows).

It generates data based on Start Date, End Date and Merchant input from users, read by SQL stored procedure here and retrieved by the code on VB.NET for Excel sheet generation

```
select * 
from (
select KioskBatchID, sum(a.BillTransactionTotal + a.ReloadTransactionTotal) as BatchTotal
From tblExcelD002 a with(nolock)
left join tblMerchant b with (nolock) on a.Merchant = b.MerchantCode
where 
(cast(CollectionDate as date) between cast(@strStartDate as date) and cast(@strEndDate as date))
And (b.MerchantCode = @strMerchant)
group by KioskBatchID
) As q1
FULL OUTER JOIN(
select CollectionDate, sum(BillTransactionTotal + ReloadTransactionTotal) as RowTotalTransaction,
sum(BillTransactionCount + ReloadTransactionCount) as RowTotalCount,KioskBatchID
From tblExcelD002 a with(nolock)
left join tblMerchant b with (nolock) on a.Merchant = b.MerchantCode
where 
(cast(CollectionDate as date) between cast(@strStartDate as date) and cast(@strEndDate as date))
And (b.MerchantCode = @strMerchant)
group by KioskBatchID, CollectionDate
) AS Q2
on q1.KioskBatchID = Q2.KioskBatchID 
order by Q2.KioskBatchID, CollectionDate
desc
```

snippet of code that retrieves the Stored Proc

```
For Each row In dsData.Tables(0).Rows

                strTableName = "tbl" + row("Merchant").ToString()

                Dim Parameters2 As New List(Of SqlParameter)
                Parameters2.Add(New SqlParameter("@strStartDate", strAppStartDate))
                Parameters2.Add(New SqlParameter("@strEndDate", strAppEndDate))
                Parameters2.Add(New SqlParameter("@strMerchant", row("Merchant")))

                If Not modDBCommon.ReadDataSetByStoredProcedure(StoredProc, Parameters2, strTableName, enuDatabase.dbMESH_BODB, dsD002, strMessage) = 0 Then
                    LogError(DEFAULT_LOG_PATH, DEFAULT_LOG_NAME, "Failed To Read StorePro", FunctionName)
                Else
                    dsData1.Tables.Add(dsD002.Tables(0).Copy())
                    dsData2.Tables.Add(dsD002.Tables(1).Copy())
                End If

            Next
```

dsData2 retrieves the second query from Stored Proc since its below another query in it. As you can see, it'll group the criteria into tblMerchant. Hence, if the user inputs 'ALL' for merchant, it will retrieve all Merchants and sort them into different tables (in my case, i put 'ALL' for Merchant and Start Date = 04-02-2021, End Date = 07-02-2021 resulting in two existing merchants between the dates: tbl0007 and tbl0008)

How do I make the output come out like this query result below? I want to make the summary table of KioskBatchID with its BatchTotal summed up according to KioskBatchID. The output of the query on SQL Server itself is already correct, thus I have to fix the loop so it comes out like it.

[image: Expected output (run in SQL)]

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Have you considered what the actual process is to go from the existing output to the desired output, i.e. what the code actually has to do? If not, why not? If so, why haven't you explained it here as it is the very core of your question?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit lost here as to what exactly your question is.  Is it the result set of the Stored Procedure isn't what you're expecting maybe?  What exactly are you expecting from that?

Comment: count me in as also being 100% lost as to what the heck and hell this person wants. I mean, what criteria is to be used to get those 3 rows? And why are the totals of those 3 rows not a sum or summary of the 5 rows? I see no rhyme or reason as to how those 3 rows were picked, and why only those 3 rows are to be the result? What is the logic or criteria for only including those 3 rows?  I wonder if there is some award on the internet for those with a gift to confuse the daylights out of posters?

Comment: @Hursey the result set of the SP is what I'm expecting. It's because of the existing function that passes the Merchant criteria into different tables that results in the current output. If I hadn't had the function in my code, it would come out perfectly just like the output on SQL server. But the function filters merchant criteria and I can't delete that function.

Answer (score 1):

> The output of the query on SQL Server itself is already correct

Awesome, so you have some working query like:

```
SELECT * FROM whatever
```

You can download the data into a datatable:

```
Using da as New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM whatever", "your conn string here")
  Dim dt = new DataTable
  da.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

You can use a library called EPPlus to make it into an excel file really easily like this:

```
Using ep as new ExcelPackage(fileinfo_or_stream_here))
  ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("SheetNameHere").Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true)
  ep.Save()
End Using
```

This is good because you don't have to have excel installed and you don't have to post a thousand lines of code that confuses everyone on SO ;)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this one just copies straight from the sql into excel. in my code there's a function that filters the criteria 'Merchant' and sort it into a table before passing it to my loop. If i try the code you suggested, it'll result in ALL merchants without going through the filtering function

Comment: You said *"The output of the query on SQL Server itself is already correct"* - so that's not actually true? Do the filtering in the stored procedure then, to save dragging a load of merchants over the network that you ultiamtely don't want.

Comment: Ultimately, you should always consider every answer on SO to be a helpful pointer in the right direction; rather than a gratis "write my whole program for me". You remain responsible for the output and we give our personal time to help you with the bits you're stuck on. If you wrote a question "How do I write a hello world program?" and someone said "Like `Console.WriteLine("HW")`" you wouldn't complain "but that just prints HW, I wanted Hello World" - you'd just change *HW* to *Hello World*. You can add some filtering in between the VB code blocks I wrote, or you can do it in the SQL (better)

Comment: okay thank you for your time, I just had a hard time explaining this. Apologies for the insolence.